# How to adopt drop down menu for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to adopt drop down menu for mobile devices?

```
  <li id="citylink">
     Киев <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>
    <ul>
      <a href="odessa.html" id="odd"><li>Одесса</li></a>
         </ul>

  </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
  ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;

  padding: 15px 30px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font-family: regular;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 68px 20px;

  background: #313131;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 184px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #1bbc9b; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: it works almost as it is: http://jsfiddle.net/w7h7gr0w/

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio what do you mean? there is basically no hover(mouse on) on mobile devices

Comment: since your first LI doesn't contain a link, you can just touch it on your smartphone, that will emulate the css hover state. you can try it on chrome inspecting the page with smartphone emulation.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio tried it on my iPhone instantly - doesn't work

Comment: Phrases like "doesn't work" are very ambiguous. Please [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33003098/edit) with a brief description of the actual result - *and* what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: touch devices trigger the hover state after its been clicked. I believe this is due to the 300ms delay to register an actual click event vs just touching something. 

either way, in this scenario you should enable some JavaScript to monitor the "state" of the clicked element. 

EX:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

touch devices trigger the hover state after its been clicked. I believe this is due to the 300ms delay to register an actual click event vs just touching something.

either way, in this scenario you should enable some JavaScript to monitor the "state" of the clicked element.

EX:
- Set initial state (probably to false as its closed)
- On click, check state (see if its set to true or false)
- If set to false, change state to true, add class to enable the 'active' state
- If set to true, change the state to false, remove the 'active' state to close the menu.

This way you can monitor state and apply an appropriate class based on state. This will provide an easy way to manage state with interaction while keeping styles separate.

Your state-based CSS classes will essential change the layout (hidden or opened nav)